# UITableView with dynamic controls - Vertically and horizontally

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

In my iPad App, requirement is like that we need to make a dynamic form where rows and columns will be generated based on JSON file (it will come from server). Refer screenshot for how it should look like. After "Men" and "Women" columns, there might more columns come from JSON and so that rows also. Also, textbox may come instead of Checkbox/label which will based on `control_id`.

> For that, I have thought 2 options:

1. UICollectionView in every UITableViewCell: In that case, the issue is that scrolling will be not like a form. Individual UICollectionView will be scrolled horizontally.
2. I can add controls in UIScrollView in for loop: In that case, reading user entered values can be headache.

So, above solutions does not seems a good and I am finding another way of doing it in proper manner. Any help or suggestion would be appreciable. I'm desperate for the solution as we have to achieve it somehow in the best way we can.

[image]

Comment: I dont think you need a tableview at all, you can build that whole layout using a UICollectionView, just create a custom layout

Comment: Here is a [good starting example](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/), although the code examples are in objective-c, its easy to convert and shows how to create complex views using custom UICollectionViewLayouts

Comment: Thanks for reply. In that case, if user scrolls, individual cell will be scrolled. If I have misunderstood, can you elaborate ?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, with a collectionView you can limit scrolling to either vertically, horizontally or both. refer to the article linked above as it explains custom collection view layouts much better than I can